# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException or Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I am new to Junit test cases. Could some one please help me with the below issue.

My project structure is as below:
    src/main/java -> sources
    src/main/resources -> /Spring/Context -> contains application-context.xml
    src/test/java -> all junit test classes

I am trying to load application-context.xml using annotation

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:*/application-context.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class LoadTest {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ProcessManager processManager=(ProcessManager)context.getBean("processManager");
        //Rest of the code
    }
}
```

If I run the above test I am getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

I tried changing

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations ={"classpath:spring/context/application-context.xml"})
```

If I do so I am getting  Failed to load ApplicationContext error

Comment: Isn't it a case typo: for "Spring/Context" when you tried:  locations ={"classpath:spring/context/application-context.xml"}

Comment: Nope. It is present in src/main/resources/spring/context/application-context.xml. I am not sure about the classpath.My test cases are present in src/test/java. All XML files are under src/main/resources. After mvn clean install the xml file is copied under target-classes-spring-context.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to autowire the Context itself just to get the real bean (ProcessManager) out of it, simply go for the bean itself:

```
@Autowired
ProcessManager processManager;
```

and just call an existing function on the autowired bean to verify that your new Spring test is working fine.

(what you were trying to do is getting the ApplicationContext out of the ApplicationContext)